How do I access Met Office daily temperature records for Cambridge UK for 2024?
I have just signed up for the Met Office Data Hub. I'm pretty sure I'll be well less than their 1GB limit for personal users. But I have no idea how to access their data. All I need is the daily temperature records for Cambridge, UK. Though wind speeds would be an added bonus.
Maybe there are easier ways to the same data?
I have registered on the site:
https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/services/data/met-office-weather-datahub
Their flow says I should select a product next, but I'm not sure what product or how I find & select the data I want.

This is not a programming problem. You need to study the MetOffice API documentation and FAQs.

Thanks for your response. I have read the FAQs (didn't really help me which is why I came here as their site recommended) nor am not sure what is a good program to use to call the API from.

I think you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance on the use of this site.
